# MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI When trying to update a user profile image in Azure AD from application

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory

I have built an application that use Azure AD to authenticate users. In my web application, I have a profile page, in which the user can edit contact information and profile picture.

The permissions for the application have been approved by a global adminstration, and are as follows:

```
Delegated - Contacts.ReadWrite
Application - Contacts.ReadWrite
Delegated - Group.ReadWrite.All
Application - Group.ReadWrite.All
Delegated - User.Read
Delegated - User.ReadWrite
Delegated - User.ReadWrite.All
Application - User.ReadWrite.All
```

I'm currently having trouble updating the user profile picture in Azure AD (Which is displayed for the user on the website). I have tried to update the profile picture on behalf of the user, with a usertoken - But without any luck.

I then found this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/profilephoto-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), that describes how profile pictures effectively should be updated in Azure AD with the applications own token.

I have followed the "tutorial", and I can't see that I'm currently doing anything wrong, my code are as follows:

```
export const updateUserProfileImage = async (file) => {
    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = `Bearer ###TOKEN###`
    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
    headers.append("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
    const options = {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: headers,
        body: file
    };
    return fetch(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/USERLOGIN@MAIL.COM/photo/$value`, options)
}
```

When I post my request, I get the following response:

```
response:
    error:
        code: "MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI"
        innerError:
            client-request-id: "MYCLIENTID"
            date: "2021-08-21T17:08:14"
            request-id: "MYREQUESTID"
        message: "The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise."
```

As far as I can understand, this behaviour is expected, i.e. from the article it says:

> Note: When updating the user photo, this operation first attempts to
> update the photo in Microsoft 365. If that fails (due to the user not
> having a mailbox), this API will attempt to update the photo in Azure
> Active Directory.

However, nothing happens after the error response - In other words, It seems as if Graph only attempts to update the photo in Microsoft 365, and then ends the operation with an error response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to update profile photos via Graph API. However, v1.0 of the API only works with Exchange Online and not Azure AD, so the user account you are trying to update must be present in **Exchange Online**. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/profilephoto?view=graph-rest-1.0) tells more  about the Profile Photo resource type.

If one tries to use the Graph API to update the photo of a **user who does not have an Exchange Online mailbox** it returns an error:

```
{"error":{"code":"MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI","message":"The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise.","innerError":{"date":"2021-07-19T12:49:54","request-id":"0a94b5f4-47ff-4f8c-8f24-b2f9622ba877","client-request-id":"0a94b5f4-47ff-4f8c-8f24-b2f9622ba877"}}}
```

To get a valid Office 365 mailbox, submit a request to your Exchange or Global administrator to migrate the mailbox account. Users who don't have administrator permissions can't migrate accounts. For information on how to migrate the mailbox account, see [How to migrate mailbox data by using the Exchange Admin Center in Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/move-or-migrate-mailboxes/migrate-data-with-admin-center)

If a **user has Exchange Online then do so via the Graph API** or **Set-UserPhoto**.
Refer this [document](https://rakhesh.com/azure/profile-photos-and-graph-api/) for more details.

And Also try with using **user's work or school mailboxes and not personal mailboxes**

Please refer this [document](https://rakhesh.com/azure/profile-photos-and-graph-api/)  for more details

Comment: Thanks alot, @ShrutiJoshi-MT that makes sense! I'm not sure we want to create an Office365 mailbox for this. So I may go ahead and use the beta API to update AAD